List does not change color on iOS 17.4.1?
Title says it all. I'm doing everything right, and can see changes at the simulator of iOS 15.5, but not on iOS 17.4.1.
15.5
17.4.1
    init() {
        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
        UICollectionView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    }

               List {
                    ForEach(items, id: \.id) { item in
                        HStack {
                            /...
                        }
                        .listRowBackground(Color(red: 0.56, green: 0.53, blue: 0.73))
                    }
                    .onDelete { indexSet in
                       /...
                    }
                }
                .padding(.top)
                .background(Color(red: 0.37, green: 0.31, blue: 0.61))


have you tried adding .listStyle(.plain) to the List
